# WCF service starts up takes 10 seconds with a big service contract having 1000 methods

Tags: wcf, service, contract

I'm using a named-pipe WCF service, which has about 1000 methods (yes, I know it's not a good practice, but it's life...).

The problem I got is that when starting up the WCF service, it costs about 10 seconds on constructor of `ServiceHost` class. By tracking into it, I found the time is spent on preparing service description (`InitializeDescription` method of `ServiceHostBase` class). I guess it's because there are too many methods defined in this service contract.

**Anyone can help to answer how can I speed up the start up time of this big service contract?**

I know it's not a good practice to define so many methods in one service contract. But I can't change the service contract (such as divide it to several smaller ones). You know, this is the real life...

Thanks.

Comment: If not being able to refactor horrible designs is your life, then I'd strongly advise to change your life. WCF has to find all methods and types it needs to publish to create the metadata (WSDL et al), which gets inherently slower the more types and methods you have.

Comment: Good ieal :) But changing my life is not my plan in the short future. Come back to the question. This WCF service resides in a desktop application (Windows based), self-host, used to communicate with another process. All methods defined in the contract are necessary. User may start this application at anytime, and may call any one operation among the 1000 ones. So we have to prepare all methods when starting up. I wonder if I can speed up the time to prepare them. For example, 'pre-prepare' them before start? Maybe 'pre-compile' it and same to some file before start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring this endpoint, while non-trivial, is probably fairly easy to do if you manage the process properly:

1. Pick a single logical business case which your endpoint currently supports.
2. Create a list of all the operations needed to fulfil this single logical business operation.
3. Create a new endpoint for just those operations, keeping the same operation signatures.
4. Re-point any existing consumers who want to fulfil this business case to the new endpoint.
5. Repeat process until you have covered all business cases.

Apologies this does not address original question directly and appreciate re-working on this scale may be outside the scope of your current development.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your great suggestions.
Finally, I decided to refactor it, and I DID it! I managed to split the big contract to a few smaller ones and host them in a few WCF hosts. Now the time used to initialized WCF hosts is reduced to less than 1.5 seconds.
So, remember to try your best before give up~~~

Comment: Nice one - enjoy your new services!